# Fully Wipe Nexus Device

Tags: adb, factory-reset, fastboot

I have a Nexus 7 2013 WiFi-only (flo) device. I rooted it and just generally messed around with it. Now I want to put it back to complete stock everything (bootloader, recovery, ROM, etc) AND COMPLETELY WIPE THE DEVICE. When following the tutorial detailed here: [Tutorial](http://www.androidbeat.com/2013/11/flash-factory-image-nexus-device/), an inspection with TWRP file manager (ON A NON-ROOTED DEVICE) shows that under '/', there is still a directory called 'SuperSU' (evidence that I rooted). It's clear that wiping the device in this way is not incredibly thorough. How can I put my Nexus back to COMPLETE, wiped stock (as though I had literally just opened the box from the factory)?

Many Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can download and flash a factory image from here: https://developers.google.com/android/nexus/images#razorktu84p it also includes instructions at the top on how to do it. This will restore it completely to stock.

Comment: From Laurence "This is me (Laurence) on a different account - lost access to old one! Thanks for the very prompt response. Are you sure that flashing the above image returns the device to full stock (with no evidence as to what was on it before)? If so, I must have imagined the instance of 'SuperSU' under '/'... Strange :-/"

Comment: Yes flashing the above image returns to full stock. Just the way it would come out of a factory.